# gWidgets: add/remove rows from gdf

Tags: r, gwidgets

How do we add/remove rows from gdf ?
EXAMPLE

```
DataFrame <- data.frame(cbind(x=1, y=1:10))
obj <- gdf(DataFrame, container = TRUE)
```

How do we add/remove rows from obj ?

Comment: You don't need to use cbind when creating a data frame.  It's slower and less readable than simply `data.frame(x=1, y=1:10)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, in design you can do assignment via [<-

```
obj[11,] <- list(x=1, y=11)
rownames(obj)[11] <- "new row name"
```

That works for gWidgetsRGtk2 (with some complaint about a color), but may not for other toolkits. (Not even gWidgets2RGtk2 on github, which is something to fix!)

As for removing rows, one could do:

```
obj[] <- obj[-5,]
```

Again working in gWidgetsRGtk2, but YMMV with the other toolkits.